# DC-DC Converter voltage drop on load

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-cell, voltage

I bought a DC-DC converter to charge my devices with the 20V 1Amp current of my solar panel. I set it so it would convert to 5V but when I connect to load the voltage drops to 4.7V or less depending on the device.

My phone actually only draws 60 mA on 4.5V; but if I change the output of the DC-DC converter to 6.5V it drops to 5.1V on load and my phone charges just fine drawing 1.1A.

I'm concerned for other devices though, they won't make the voltage drop so much and 6.5V could be too much. Is there a way I can stabilize the voltage to 5V preventing voltage drop?

I tested the circuit always with high sunlight: measured 20V 1A out of the solar panel (max power rated 20W). With a multimeter I measured the max current and was 2.6A out of the DC-DC converter with a voltage drop to 4.5V (5V base).

DC-DC converter specifications: 3-40V input, 1.3-37V output, max 3A (2A suggested with regular use).
[image]

Comment: It's one of those cheap 2596 devices. I've damaged similar ones (made them no longer function the way they are supposed to) by doing nothing more than failing to supply a reasonable load when powering it up. So for those I still have in a box here, I always make sure they have a reasonable load at the output *before* supplying power to them. Since doing so, I've had zero failures. (Two dead before that taught me my lesson.) The failed behavior on the two is about what you describe.

Comment: Why did you delete your identical question from yesterday?

Answer (score 3):

These cheap "LM2596" modules are usually [fake and counterfeit](https://k6jca.blogspot.com/2018/02/counterfeit-lm2596-regulator-boards.html). Sometimes they don't even bother to fake the National logo and font right, and the chip isn't even a fake LM2596 since it runs at the wrong frequency. Probably some other chip being relabeled.

On the ones I tested, it ran at about 50kHz instead of 150kHz. But the inductor had been designed for 150kHz, so it saturated.

Eventually the low quality, high-ESR output cap will die and output voltage ripple will go out of control, destroying the load, but that shouldn't happen when it's new.

Solution: replace counterfeit DC-DC with good brand, you got Recom, Traco, Murata and the other usual suspects for a few bucks at mouser/farnell/digikey.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like we may be seeing similar things except that you spent more time than I did looking into the details. I paid about 40 cents each for mine in a box of 25, each with two pots: one for current limit threshold and the other for the output voltage. At that price? I went for it. Threw away two I'd killed. And have been completely successful with another four I've actually applied here and there, once I realized they needed a load on the output to survive a power-up event. Luckily, I only use them for toy purposes, as I'm just a hobbyist.

Comment: You could get much better reliability and output ripple by changing the output cap with a low-ESR model, but if your "LM2596" is actually another chip that runs at 50k instead of 150kHz that won't fix the inductor saturation which is the main source of output ripple. And once you change the inductor too, you've spent $2 and 10 minutes on a 50c module lol.

Comment: Usually I use [these](https://fr.farnell.com/en-FR/recom-power/r-78e5-0-1-0/convertisseur-dc-dc-5v-1-a-trav/dp/2760747) (available in 500mA and 1A version). For one-off projects, 4€ for a canned DC-DC versus a few hours to design and layout one... easy choice!

Comment: Much as I hate to bother, curiosity means I probably have to go look at the ones I have in the box when I get a moment. I could just let it go since I know how to get what I want from them now. But being curious, I'll spend the time at some point soon. Your info directs the effort, and thanks, so it won't be hard. As far as the module you point to, it's fixed output. I also have a box full of similar fixed DC-DC, at different useful voltages, and no problems with any. These "flaky" 2596 ones I have are variable output voltage with settable current limiting. Sometimes I need that when playing.

Comment: (I had bought all 25 when I only needed just one at the time as it was almost the same price either way. Only when they arrived and I destroyed a couple trying them out, did I tumble to the idea of loading them down first before powering. I've tested a few without the load and some are destroyed, some are not. But loaded, they always "just work." They won't get used on anything I really care about and I have a lifetime supply of them. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advices, so there's nothing i can do, i just have to buy a better product... I kind of always used Amazon because of the free and fast shipping but I know it's not a good place to buy specific electronics components. I searched on other sites but i have a problem finding the right product for me at a resonable cost. I live in Italy. I would need to convert 20V 1A to 5V at least 2.5A (and really for another project i would need to convert also from 20V 1A to 12V 1A). Can someone suggest some products?

Comment: @FrancescoFattori Okay. You have two specs now. And that is a good thing. Not bad. You want a 20 V to 5 V at 2.5 A output and you also may want a 20 V to 12 V at 1.0 A output. This is immediately a problem if you want them both at the same time. That is because 20 V at 1 A is 20 W and the sum of 5 V at 2.5 A and 12 V at 1 A exceeds this as it is 24.5 W. Do you need these at the same time? If not, good. If so, then there is already a fundamental problem.

Comment: I know, I do not need them at the same time.

Comment: @FrancescoFattori "Shopping" (aka product recommendations) are off-topic.